# Play framework 2.x - How to automate version changes and releases for production deployment

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm on the process of release a play app to production. So far most of my experience has been with java projects, using maven with maven-release-plugin, for version incrementing, creating a version tag in git, etc.

How to handle releases and version changes with play framework?

I found a few mentions about sbt-release, but haven't found a complete tutorial or a sample project.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on you requirements, in my experience I haven't had much need to do the whole *build-test-commit-tag-release-commit* dance, but then I have used it in continuous-delivery-like circumstances. Just making sure that there is something marking what VCS-revision a certain binary is (for example using [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo)) and then using plays [dist](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production#Using-the-dist-task) has been enough.

If you really need it the `sbt-release` plugin has got [a pretty detailed documentation](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release). I would try with that to begin with.

Comment: I'm also going for a continuous delivery like flow, I just need to keep a record of what is in production, rollback to a previous version if the a deploy goes wrong, etc. Have you been able to do that using sbt-buildinfo?